# How to validate time "10:30 AM" in laravel validator

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.8

I am Using a Laravel validator and want to make the time required. I googled and didn't find any solution regarding my time format `10:30 AM`.
I have used `date_format` but did not have any luck.
Here is my code

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            'appointment-date'  => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
            'slot'=>'required|date_format:H:i',
        ]
    );
```

This show error that slot is invalid. My request is `"slot" => "02:00 AM"`.

Comment: You need to provide that format, then. `H:i a`. The `am` part is the `a` format, which you did not provide.

Comment: [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/l5-how-to-validate-date-input-before-passing-to-rules-method-in-a-form-request) solution?

Comment: I have also tried 'slot'=>'required|date_format:H:i a',  and 'slot'=>'required|date_format:g:i a', but found same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you're after, the validation should be:

```
'slot' => 'required|date_format:h:i A'
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), your current format does not check for the AM/PM section of the time (I would also assume that `H` should be `h` as you shouldn't need a 24 hour format if you have `AM/PM`).

The above format broken down is:

- **h**: 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros
- **i**: Minutes with leading zeros
- **A**: AM/PM (uppercase not lowercase)